# Mozilla not showing proper font

Tags: html, css, fonts

Not sure if I'm repeating a question, but I have this issue with webfont. I'm using Gotham font, and It works in chrome, but won't render in Mozilla. Mozilla just gives me some basic font. Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'gotham_boldregular';
src: url('../fonts/gotham-bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/gotham-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/gotham-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/gotham-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/gotham-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/gotham-bold-webfont.svg#gotham_boldregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'gotham_lightregular';
    src: url('../fonts/gotham-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/gotham-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/gotham-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/gotham-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/gotham-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/gotham-light-webfont.svg#gotham_lightregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Gotham`, `Gotham Light` or `Gotham Book`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham';
}
```

Comment: I think it's not about how the font is called, just something that can make it work on other browsers.

Comment: @Ognjen take a look here at the bottom of the page (last comment), I think it'll solve your issue:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/987469

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Firefox does not support the EOT file type and makes the whole @font-face code invalid. Try removing it and only putting the WOFF file in the CSS.

This way works on every browser:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Souses';
    src: url('../font/souses/Souses.eot');
    src: url('../font/souses/Souses.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../font/souses/Souses.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('../font/souses/Souses.svg#Souses') format('svg');
}
```

Reference: https://support.mozilla.org/es/questions/987469

Hope it helps!

Edited code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Souses';
    src: url('Souses.eot');
    src: url('Souses.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('Souses.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('Souses.svg') format('svg');
}
body { 
    font-family: 'Souses';
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Comment: Try using the code above and replace it with your own font and url. Notice that it has a EOT file in one src and the others font files in another src without the IEFIX EOT.

Comment: Add your current code here so we can see where's the problem with it (the one with the last modification you did)...

Comment: Can't seem to figure out what is changed, you just put the font files directly and not in fonts folder? Tried this, also doesn't work :/